# how to set nginx with rtmp (mp3) audio?

Tags: nginx, audio, rtmp

I have ubuntu 18.04 and I was install nginx with rtmp module and when I send live audio and video - audio not work. codec from video is h 264 and audio mp3. how to make audio to be work?

Comment: Hi mastersam. Perhaps you should start with the dedicated Google group : https://groups.google.com/g/nginx-rtmp/search?q=no%20sound
I hope this group is active, or someone here could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: nginx-rtmp does not support mp3 over HLS, but there are some workarounds.

But because you didn't describe your use scenario with more detail, let me discuss it in general scenarios.

### Publish MP3 Live Stream

You can use FFmpeg to publish live stream, or you should get an encoder which supports MP3 audio codec. For example:

```bash
ffmpeg -re -i doc/source.flv -vcodec copy -acodec libmp3lame \
    -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/livestream
```

> Not: OBS only support AAC audio codec, as I know.

You can use [nginx-rtmp](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) or [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs) as media server, then play the RTMP stream by:

- FFPLAY: `ffplay rtmp://localhost/live/livestream`
- VLC: `rtmp://localhost/live/livestream`

You might want to covert RTMP to other protocols for other players such as H5 or mobile phone, let me describe it in next section.

### Play MP3 Live Stream

Viewers literally never use ffplay or VLC as player, but use H5 or mobile phone, so you must covert MP3 over RTMP to other protocols, which might not be supported by some media server.

HLS is the most common used protocol for player, please note that nginx-rtmp does not support MP3 over HLS, see [#181](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/181). After some research, I found that nginx-rtmp force to use AAC in HLS stream, so you must fix it by merging [this](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/pull/263) patch.

Another workaround is to use [SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs), which supports MP3 over HLS and other protocols. For detail usage, please see [#296](https://github.com/ossrs/srs/issues/296). For example:

- MP3 over HLS: Supported. Recommend to enable `hls_acodec mp3;` to make the first segment written without change PMT of HLS.
- MP3 over HTTP-TS: Supported. You can use [mpegts.js](https://github.com/xqq/mpegts.js) H5 player to play the live stream, which has low latency than HLS.
- Covert MP3 to WebRTC(Opus): Supported. Use WebRTC to play the live stream, is another solution.

However, you can covert MP3 codec to AAC by FFmpeg, because AAC is widely used now and almost all servers and players support AAC, however it consumes more CPU (about 2% per stream) for audio transcoding:

```bash
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/live/livestream -vcodec copy -acodec aac \
    -f flv rtmp://localhost/live/livestream-aac
```

PS: Note that you can also do pure audio live stream, by deliver by HTTP-MP3. And if need to DVR the live stream, both FLV and MP4 are ok.